# chai assert array of objects by value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, assert, chai

Is it possible with chai to assert an array of objects by value?

Here is my code:

```
var expected = [
    {
        a: 10
    }
];

var actual = [
    {
        a: '10'
    }
];

// ...

assert.sameDeepMembers(expected, actual);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
AssertionError: expected [ { a: 10 } ] to have the same members as [ { a: '10' } ]
```

So I would like chai to ignore the type of property: a.

Answer (score 1):

Your types are different. By chai's definition of `sameDeepMembers`:

```
Asserts that set1 and set2 have the same members - using a deep equality checking. Order is not taken into account.
```

Deep equality in javascript is `===`so as expected int type `10` is not the same and string type `'10'`

`(10 === '10') // false`

Perhaps chai's `assert.sameMembers` is what you are looking for.

Comment: That is clear. Maybe my question is not. I'm looking for a solution that ignores types. I need a solution instead of `sameDeepMembers` that asserts by value. Thanks @Jay

Comment: for `assert.sameMembers(expected, actual, 'not ok');` it gives `AssertionError: not ok: expected [ { a: 10 } ] to have the same members as [ { a: '10' } ]`

Comment: I have tried most of the array assertions in chai without success. I'm not satisfied with it's doc, because it rarely mentions that if an assertion checks the type or not. Also I would be surprised if there wasn't any solution for this in chai.

Comment: I agree this documentation is not very good. I know this is not the answer you are looking for but if this is a test function perhaps you can rework the assertion check.